# How can I monitor disk access for a certain file?

Tags: disk, performance

I want to use performance monitors to determine when a file is being accessed (read/write). Is this possible? If not, is there any other way?
My OS is Windows Server 2008 R2, and I am writing the code in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what its worth, you can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to monitor writes to a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there is an API available for doing this using managed code.  If you need to hook a file system read or write event, you should look into writing a [filter driver](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx).  Filter drivers are pretty low-level constructs and if it's only to do performance monitoring then it's probably not worth it. This API is often utilized by anti-virus or backup/replication software developers.